# How to add a param as optional on GET request Axios

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, get

I need param "similarText" to be optional ¿How can I do that?
If I add value? I get warnings from linter.

```
export const getProducts = async (
  value: string,
  apiKey: string | undefined
) => {
  const products = await axios
    .get(`${VITE_BACKEND_URI}/products?param1=match_token&param2=match_token`, {
       params: {
       similarText: value,
       },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        'Content-Type': 'Content-Type',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error
    })
  return products
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optionally adding the params, you can use `spread operator`, for example `...value ?? { similarText: value }`.

```
export const getProducts = async (
  value: string,
  apiKey: string | undefined
) => {
  const products = await axios
    .get(`${VITE_BACKEND_URI}/products?param1=match_token&param2=match_token`, {
       params: {
         ...value ?? { similarText: value },
       },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        'Content-Type': 'Content-Type',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error
    })
  return products
}
```